# Messed up inputrc file, can't type d to sudo to fix it

Tags: command-line, bash, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux, inputrc

I'm using the Linux subsystem on Windows 10, running Ubuntu bash.  I was trying to disable the windows error ding every time I tab completed something, and now I can't type 'd' (or `CAPS{shift{d}}`, or paste in 'd' following the instructions given by this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36724209/disable-beep-of-linux-bash-on-windows-10 . In my etc/inputrc file, I uncommented the line `set bell-style none` as directed, as well as the line above it which was something about `<no bell sound on tab completion>`.

Here is a similar question, but it doesn't quite work for me:
[lower-case 'c' key not working in bash](https://askubuntu.com/questions/152327/lower-case-c-key-not-working-in-bash)
I originally used `sudo vim inputrc` in order to save my edits on the read only file, but now I can't type a 'd' to do that with.  I couldn't get the other recommendations for saving a read only to work.  Running as admin didn't help.

What else should I be trying?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Super obvious solution, since I'm using the windows subsystem for linux, just go into the folder on windows and edit from there.